# Angular 12 sub routes 404 loosing context on refresh

Tags: node.js, angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I am having problem with angular 12 sub routes. I can navigate to the sub routes just fine but when I refresh the page I lose context. I am running it locally on the localhost:4200
here is the image of what I am getting in network tab and on the screen when I refresh
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUcSb.png)

here is a link for source code: https://github.com/Stanmozolevskiy/Portfolio

Here is routing component:

```
import { SinglePortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/single-portfolio/single-portfolio.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'about/portfolio', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent},
  {path: 'portfolio/:query', component: SinglePortfolioComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is app module:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { GetintouchComponent } from './getintouch/getintouch.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { SinglePortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/single-portfolio/single-portfolio.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './common/header/header.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AsideComponent } from './common/aside/aside.component';
import { ParagraphComponent } from './common/paragraph/paragraph.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    GetintouchComponent,
    PortfolioComponent,
    SinglePortfolioComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    AsideComponent,
    ParagraphComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule ,
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I will be happy to try any suggestions, thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean “lose context”? What information is lost on refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem:
Change your webserver configurations to match your location strategy or use HashLocationStrategy as follow: `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,  {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', useHash: true})]`

And please change all **href** attributes over your code base to **routerLink** directive as follow:

```
<a routerLink="/portfolio" class="btn btn-lg edit_hover_class custom-btn">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faBriefcase"></fa-icon> My portfolio 
                   </a>
```

Comment: Thank you LXhelili, useHash:trur resolves my problem along with the routerLink.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the index.html fallback that doesn't work on the production like it works locally while in development.

You can fix your issue by looking at the docs here https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml.

Just know what is your online server and do the solution specific for it.